# How read the Wrapped Array in python

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

If I want to retrieve the Categories, then how can I access the value of the wrapped array of categories the tree is shown as in the image.

[image]

Comment: Please don't post images and consider adding a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185/8371915). What output do you want?

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df.select(F.explode("categories")).show()
```

another way could be also to use `getItems` method applied to your column categories.